# font-size:14px do not works

Tags: css

I had tried to visit github with Chrome devtools' mobile device mode. I found that github use 14px as the value of font-size,and it works nice. Then I set 14px to my own html file, but the result is quite different.
[image]

as you can see, 14px is too small for my own project even if it's font-size equals github's.

Comment: Did you try to set another value? does it change the size?

Comment: Sometimes font-size depends on font-family try to apply the same font-size with the same font-family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are viewing in small viewport. Add the below meta tag in head and check again

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```